# Coffeescript, RequireJS, Backbone - @ is out of scope

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, coffeescript, requirejs

I have following code

```
define [
  "jquery", 
  "backbone", 
  "underscore",
  "models/days"
], ($, Backbone, _, days) =>

  class Calendar extends Backbone.View

    el          : "#calendar_box"
    collection  : days

    display: =>
      @collection.fetch_data
        month :8
        year  :2012
      , @render

    render: =>
      # console.log @collection - gives "undefined"
      console.log @ # this returns "Window" instead of "Calendar" - current obj.

  # return the calendar object
  new Calendar()
```

It's a BackboneView in Coffeescript, which requests the server to get the days of the given month and year as a calendar.

The data is returned fine, because I can check it in the Chrome console - the GET request and its response.

However, within the "render" function, it looks like "@" is at the global level, instead of within the "Calendar" level.

What happened here?

Answer (score 1):

Check the backbone.js docs on [binding this](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this) and then add an initialize- function into your Calendar and use the underscore `bindAll` -function to bind render and other methods to have the right context

NOT COFFEESCRIPT:

```
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'display');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but when using coffeescript, I don't think you need to do "_.bindAll".

Comment: the bind to this is already done by using `=>` in the function definition. `=> foo;` is equivalent to `_.bind(function(){foo;},this)` in javascript/underscore.

Comment: nice, thanks for the info, maybe i'll have a look into CoffeeScript

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing

```
($, Backbone, _, days) =>
```

to

```
($, Backbone, _, days) ->
```

That seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify why changing fat arrow => to thin arrow -> works, is because of discrimination the Coffeescript compiler makes between these two on purpose.

**In a nutshell**: fat arrow creates a reference to the `this` keyword in the outer scope and makes the `@` symbol refer to the outer `this`

```
# Coffeescript
fatArrow => @
thinArrow -> @
```

And now the compiled Javascript:

```
// make a reference to the 'this' keyword (might be the global scope)
// for the @ symbol inside the fat arrow function
var _this = this;

fatArrow(function() {
   // the @ symbol does not actually reference 'this'
   // but the outer scope _this variable
   return _this;
});

thinArrow(function() {
   // the @ symbol in a thin arrow function
   // is the same as the 'this' keyword in javascript
   return this;
});
```

## Why?

A lot of patterns in javascript require a reference to the outer scope this, commonly referred as `self` or in the case of Coffeescript `_this`. For example in event callbacks, commonly seen in frameworks like jQuery. Coffeescript makes this easy because you can just use fat arrow instead cluttering your code with a outer scope `this` reference.

```
# Coffeescript
initializeFatGuy = ->
    @eat = (food) -> alert 'eating some #{food}'  

    # common example of event callback with double arrow
    $('body').on 'click', (event) =>
        # call the eat method
        # @ is the outer scope _this variable generated by Coffeescript
        @eat 'chips'
```